# Unknown database format

Tags: database, csv, format

I'm new to the world of large data files and I'm wondering about what the format of my data might be. The data is in a very large text file containing some anonymized medical records. I have pasted a sample below.

I understand what each column is except for the fourth column which seems to be a code relating similar rows. Does this type of data come from a relational database? If so, is there a name for this kind of format?

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
649|183|Vital Signs|33877743-BE2A-48EE-A53C-D507D59CE540|1169|Blood Pressure (Diastolic)|80
649|183|Vital Signs|33877743-BE2A-48EE-A53C-D507D59CE540|1170|Blood Pressure (Systolic)|140
649|183|Vital Signs|33877743-BE2A-48EE-A53C-D507D59CE540|1174|Vital Signs Delta|0
649|183|Vital Signs|33877743-BE2A-48EE-A53C-D507D59CE540|1175|Pulse|64
649|183|Vital Signs|33877743-BE2A-48EE-A53C-D507D59CE540|1176|Respiratory Rate|14
649|183|Vital Signs|33877743-BE2A-48EE-A53C-D507D59CE540|1178|Weight|73.7
649|183|Vital Signs|33877743-BE2A-48EE-A53C-D507D59CE540|1180|Weight Units|Kilograms
649|183|Vital Signs|ACEFCC5F-C6FA-426F-AC26-7A23D7E6B26E|1169|Blood Pressure (Diastolic)|
649|183|Vital Signs|ACEFCC5F-C6FA-426F-AC26-7A23D7E6B26E|1170|Blood Pressure (Systolic)|
```

Comment: Looks like a GUID: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier .

Comment: The 4th column contains a GUID. Without a schema impossible to say what it relates to. May be a foreign key to something defined in another file.

Comment: The definintion of columns in a file should be requested from the person or organization who provide the file or the client who expects you to consume it. While it looks as if it is a GUID to us, why they are providing it and what they expect you to do with it are part of the requirements definition process.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a normal delimited style text file using `|` as the delimiter.

It is not a specific standard but many different programs can produce and consume such files. It is not possible to tell what specific piece of software produced this.

Depending on platform and language you will be able to parse this file fairly easily - it looks like one record per line, each field separated by `|`.

The fourth column is a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier). GUIDs are very common in many applications and are many times used as identifiers in very large databases and in disconnected database scenarios (as their nature means that duplicates are very unlikely to be created).

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. Parsing the file as I would parse a csv is not difficult. However, the file is representing a richer structure i.e. one that could be better represented as a struct than a matrix. I've been told that it's a JSON format but it looks very different to any JSON samples I've been able to find...

Comment: @Gregor - That's certainly not JSON. I also don't see a hierarchy (or rich structure) from the example posted.

Comment: I agree that the sample is maybe not very complete. Here we are looking at patient 649 and to vital signs taken in two different days (the GUID is the same for measurements taken in the same day). For example I would put this data like this: Patients(649).VitalSigns(1).BloodPressDias = 80, Patients(649).VitalSigns(1).BloodPressSyst = 140, etc. and Patients(649).VitalSigns(2).BloodPressDias = NaN.